# Would real world Meteor application use server side Methods almost exclusively?

Tags: meteor

I'm learning Meteor and fundamentally enjoy how fast I can build data driven applications however as I went through the Creating Posts chapter in the Discover Meteor book I learned about using server side Methods.  Specifically the primary reason (and there are a number of very valid reasons to use these) was because of the timestamp.  You wouldn't want to rely on the client date/time, you'd want to use the server date/time.

Makes sense except that in almost every application I've ever built we store date/time of row create/update in a column.  Effectively every single create or update to the database records date/time which in Meteor now looks like I would need to use server side Methods to ensure data integrity.

If I'm understanding correctly that pretty much eliminates the ease of use and real-time nature of a client side Collection because I'll need to use Methods for almost every single update and create to our databases.

Just wanted to check and see how everyone else is doing this in the real world.  Are you just querying a server side Method that just returns the date/time and then using client side Collection or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a very good a thought out question. I could answer with some technical details but I will just wait for @AndrewMao to reply to this :)

Comment: If @AndrewMao doesn't post an answer i'll try posting an improved answer

Comment: I did not realize I was being roped in to answering this question. Apparently @ callouts can't be used to reference people who are not already part of a conversation.

Comment: @imslavko Next time, I would prefer a personal note if a question requires attention rather than a public shout-out :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer to this question is that yes, every operation that affects the server's database will go through a server-side method. The only difference is whether you are defining this method explicitly or not.

When you are just getting started with Meteor, you will probably do insert/update/remove operations directly on client collections using [validators](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow), which check for whether the operation is allowed. This usage is actually calling predefined methods on **both** the server and client: (for a collection named `foo` the you have `/foo/insert`, for example) which simply checks the specified validators before doing the operation. As you become more familiar with Meteor you will probably override these default methods, for reasons you described (among others.)

When using your own methods, you will typically want to define a method both on the server and the client, just as the default collection functions do for you. This is because of Meteor's [latency compensation](http://docs.meteor.com/#sevenprinciples), which allows most client operations to be reflected immediately in the browser without any noticeable lag, as long as they are permitted. Meteor does this by first *simulating* the effect of a method call in the client, updating the client's cached data temporarily, then sending the actual method call to the server. If the server's method causes a different set of changes than the client's simulation, the client's cache will be updated to reflect this when the server method returns. This also means that if the client's method would have done the same as the server, we've basically allowed for an instant operation from the perspective of the client.

By defining your own methods on the server and client, you can extend this to fill your own needs. For example, if you want to insert timestamps on updates, have the client insert whatever timestamp in the simulation method. The server will insert an authoritative timestamp, which will replace the client's timestamp when the method returns. From the client's perspective, the insert operation will be instant, except for an update to the timestamp if the client's time happens to be way off. (By the way, you may want to check out my **[timesync](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-timesync)** package for displaying relative server time accurately on the client.)

A final note: it's good to understand what scope you are doing collection operations in, as this was one of the this that originally confused me about Meteor. For example, if you have a collection instance in the client `Foo`, `Foo.insert()` in normal client code will call the default pair of client/server methods. However, `Foo.insert()` in a **client method** will run only in a simulation and will never call server code - so you will need to define the same method on the server and make sure you do `Foo.insert()` there as well, for the method to work properly.

A good rule of thumb for moving forward is to replace groups of validated collection operations with your own methods that do the same operations, and then adding specific extra features on the server and client respectively.

Comment: Don't you think this is also very dependent on the domain and scale of your application? I could think of reasons why you'd always want to update documents using a meteor method instead of via minimongo

Comment: @MarcodeJongh I agree with you. Does my answer suggest otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

In short— yes!

Publications exist to send out a 'live', and dynamic, subset of the database to the client, sending DDP `added` messages for existing records, followed by a `ready`, and then `added`, `changed`, and `deleted` messages to keep the client's cache consistent.

Methods exist to- directly, or indirectly— cause Mongo Updates, and like it was mentioned by Andrew, they are always in use.

But truly, because of Meteor's publication architecture, any edits to collections that are currently being published to at least one client, will be published via DDP - regardless of the source of the change to Mongo - even an outside process.